# zoom-in эффект при прокрутке, эффект нужен для div

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-animation, прокрутка

Ищу zoom-in эффект при прокрутке, [аналог](https://www.reformcollective.com/)
Эффект в секции з заголовком "REFORM CO".

Может кто-нибудь пояснить как это делается?
Планирую использовать рисунок (SVG маска), чтобы был выден нижний div.
Как сделать такой же эффект как в оригинале (в секции "REFORM CO")?

Благодарю.